# Show Twitter Follower Count on Website?

Tags: twitter

I know you can use the API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show), But how can I get this to appear on my website? E.g. 'Username' has 'follower count'.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=jjmpsp&include_entities=true";

$feed = file_get_contents($url);

$twitter_decoded = json_decode($feed);

echo $twitter_decoded->followers_count;

?>
```